# Замена нулей в массиве на следующее ненулевое число

Tags: javascript

Как написать метод, который будет заменять 0 на рядом идущее число:
Чтобы из этого:

```
[0, 0, 3, 0, 4]
```

Получилось это:

```
[3, 3, 3, 3, 4]
```

---

Из этого:

```
[1, 2, 4, 0, 0]
```

Вот это:

```
[1, 2, 4, 4, 4]
```

---

Из этого:

```
[1, 2, 5, 0, 5]
```

Вот это:

```
[1, 2, 5, 5, 5]
```

---

Из этого:

```
[1, 2, 0, 6, 6]
```

Вот это:

```
[1, 2, 6, 6, 6]
```

Comment: Никак. Потому что в программировании нет такого понятия "рядом идущее число".

Comment: @Igor, может и нет, но может вы знаете как сделать то, что я хочу?

Comment: Я не знаю, чего Вы хотите. Почему в одних случаях берется число справа от нуля, а в других - слева?

Comment: @Igor, да именно в этом и проблема, массив может прилететь только либо слева, либо с права, центр никогда не прилетит. Вот как это так провернуть?

Comment: Почему в Ваших примерах в одних случаях берется число справа от нуля, а в других - слева?

Comment: @Igor, потому что так приходит массив. Это разные стороны колонок, может начинаться слева на права, а также справа на лева. то есть `[0, 0, 3, 1, 2]` - это `[3, 3, 3, 1, 2]`, а `[1, 2, 0, 3, 0]` - это уже будет `[1, 2, 3, 3, 3]`. И если будет так `[0, 0, 3, 0, 3]` - это будет `[3, 3, 3, 3, 3]`. А `[0, 0, 3, 0, 4]`, будет `[3, 3, 3, 3, 4]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решен, [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62827197/replacing-going-zero-by-a-number/62827318?noredirect=1#comment111102784_62827318) - спасибо @hev1.

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 4, 0, 0];
const replacement = arr.find((n, i) => n !== 0 && arr[i - 1] === 0) || arr.find((n, i) => n !== 0 && arr[i + 1] === 0);
const res = arr.map(x => x || replacement);
console.log(res);
```